# Attempted to add SKNode which already has parent

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, physics, sknode

UPDATE:

In my initial post, I thought it was a physicsBody property error causing the crash, but that is not actually the case.

When two objects collide, it is supposed to end the game, and show the Game Over screen.  However, at random times, the app will crash.  I can't find a pattern for why it does this.  Some times it does it the first time, others, I can restart multiple times before it ever crashes the app.  I get the error:

```
'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <GameOverLayer> name:'(null)' position:{0, 0} accumulatedFrame:{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}'
```

The code in question is the last line of this method:

```
- (void) showGameOverLayer
{
    //Remove currently exising on pillars from scene and purge them
    for (int i = self.children.count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        SKNode* childNode = [self.children objectAtIndex:i];

        if(childNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == pillerCategory)
        {
            [childNode removeAllActions];
        }
    }
    [_flappyBird removeAllActions];
    _flappyBird.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0.0);
    _flappyBird.hidden = YES;

    _gameOver = YES;
    _gameStarted = NO;

    _dt = 0;
    _lastUpdateTimeInterval = 0;
    _lastSpawnTimeInterval = 0;

    [_startGameLayer removeFromParent];
    [self addChild:_gameOverLayer];
}
```

I am learning to use SpriteKit and am just following a tutorial for making a game like Flappy Bird, so this is all relatively new to me.

Every place the `_gameOverLayer removeFromParent` part is shown:

```
- (void) showStartGameLayer
{
    //Remove currently exising on pillars from scene and purge them
    for (int i = self.children.count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        SKNode* childNode = [self.children objectAtIndex:i];
        if(childNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == pillerCategory)
        {
            [childNode removeFromParent];
        }
    }

    //Move Flappy Bird node to center of the scene
    self.flappyBird.position = CGPointMake(self.backgroundImageNode.size.width * 0.5f, self.frame.size.height * 0.6f);

    [_gameOverLayer removeFromParent];

    _flappyBird.hidden = NO;
    [self flyingBird];
    [self addChild:_startGameLayer];
}

- (void) startGame
{
    _score = 0;

    _gameStarted = YES;

    [_startGameLayer removeFromParent];
    [_gameOverLayer removeFromParent];

    self.flappyBird.position = CGPointMake(self.backgroundImageNode.size.width * 0.3f, self.frame.size.height * 0.6f);

    //To have Gravity effect on Bird so that bird flys down when not tapped
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -4.0);
}
```

Comment: You didn't post the line this error occured in (addChild:). Add an exception breakpoint to see the line in question.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Sorry about that.  The error occurred right after I changed the physicsBody property, so I assumed it was the problem.  However, it was coincidence.  The app is pretty random when it crashes.  See the updated OP for the actual code problem.

Comment: Does it happen the second time you hit this code ? Also important is where it removes the _gameOverLayer if that is the case. You should put a breakpoint on any removeChild lines for that node to ensure that it gets removed. Also, do you have any other places where you addChild that node ?

Comment: Add it to the question with formatting, very hard to read code in comments. :)

Comment: @prototypical ok it is added now

Comment: So you put a breakpoint like I said on all lines with addChild and removeChild for that node ? My guess is that showGameOverLayer gets called twice in a row, or something of that nature.

Comment: delete the comments with the code, and I'll delete this comment and my comment regarding the formatting.

Comment: @prototypical When it crashes, it is running the `showGameOverLayer` method twice (listed at the beginning of the OP.

Comment: If it gets run twice in a row with no removeChild, that will cause the error. Did you set the breakpoints and check ? This boils down to you needing to debug your game via the debugger. That's what a programmer would do at this point.